# Loading file client-side in Next.JS 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

---

### System informations

- **next**: v13.4.13
- **npm**: v9.5.1
- **node**: v18.16.0

---

### The context

I'm trying to translate my app with my own module. Actually, I'm doing what the official documentation recommends (doing an API endpoint that loads the file and returns the content): https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route.

### Actually

To resume, actually, I'm preloading the translations in the top level layout, adding it to the cache with *useMemo* and using them in my client components.

### The issue

The problem is that, on such pages, I don't see the translations and have this error in console: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=422

### My question

Is there a solution to directly load the file in the browser or to improve the load of the translations or to avoid the Hydration error ?

---

### My code

The root layout (server-side):

```js
import '../styles/global.css';

import IntlContextProvider from '@evo/evo-translation/providers/context';
import { getLocale } from '@evo/evo-translation/server';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  themeColor: '#401F4D',
};

interface IProps {
  children: any;
}

export default async function RootLayout({ children }: IProps) {
  const locale = getLocale();
  return (
    <html lang={locale} className="theme-app h-full">
      <body className="h-full bg-skin-primary">
        <IntlContextProvider locale={locale}>{children}</IntlContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

The *IntlContextProvider* (client-side layout):

```js
'use client';

import { preLoadTranslations } from '../translators/useTranslationsV2';

export default function IntlContextProvider({
  children,
  locale,
}: {
  children: any;
  locale: string;
}): JSX.Element {
  preLoadTranslations(locale);
  return children;
}
```

The script that loads the translations (preLoadTranslations) and the translator (useTranslator) :

```js
import { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';

import { TranslatorV2 } from './class-translator-v2';

const cachedTranslations: any = {};

async function getApiTranslations(locale: string) {
  const url = new URL(
    '/api/localizationV2',
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL as string
  );

  const headers = {
    'Accept-Language': locale,
  };

  const request = await fetch(url, {
    headers,
    next: { revalidate: 60 * 60 }, //? 1 hour
    // cache: 'force-cache',
  });

  if (request.status === 200) {
    const data = await request.json();

    return data;
  }

  return {};
}

async function preLoadTranslations(locale: string) {
  if (!cachedTranslations[locale]) {
    cachedTranslations[locale] = await getApiTranslations(locale);
  }
}

export default function useTranslator(locale: string, namespace: string) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadTranslations = async () => {
      await preLoadTranslations(locale);
    };

    loadTranslations();
  }, [locale]);

  const translator = useMemo(() => {
    return new TranslatorV2(cachedTranslations[locale] || {}, namespace);
  }, [locale, namespace]);

  return translator.translate.bind(translator);
}

export { preLoadTranslations, useTranslator };
```

My Api endpoint's handler code (loads the file that contains the translations depending on the locale):

```js
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import path from 'path';

type Config = {
  defaultLocale: string;
  locales: string[];
};

class GetLocaleHandler {
  private config: Config;

  constructor(config: Config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  public async handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const { cookies } = req as { cookies: any };
    const { headers } = req as { headers: any };

    let locale: string = this.config.defaultLocale;

    if (
      cookies.NEXT_LOCALE &&
      this.config.locales.some((loc) => loc === cookies.NEXT_LOCALE)
    ) {
      locale = cookies.NEXT_LOCALE;
    } else if (
      headers['accept-language'] &&
      this.config.locales.some((loc) => loc === headers['accept-language'])
    ) {
      locale = headers['accept-language'];
    }

    const directory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'json');
    const fileContent = await fs.readFile(
      `${directory}/localization/${locale}.json`,
      'utf8'
    );

    const translations = JSON.parse(fileContent);

    if (translations) {
      res.status(200).json({ ...translations });
      return;
    }

    res.status(404).json({});
  }
}

export default function handler(config: Config) {
  const localeHandler = new GetLocaleHandler(config);

  return localeHandler.handler.bind(localeHandler);
}
```

The handler is called like that in the API:

```js
import localizationHandler from './localizationHandler';

const handler = localizationHandler({
  locales: ['en', 'fr'],
  defaultLocale: 'en',
});

export default handler;
```

An example of usage in a client-side component that is called in a page (server-side) called in the client-side layout :

```js
'use client';

import { useTranslator } from './client';

// The locale is sended by the page that is server-side
export function Component({ locale }: { locale: string }) {
  const t = useTranslator(locale, 'customer');

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
      <h1>{t('firstname')}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```